# Flutter Firebase Auth not working in Ecommerce app

Tags: firebase, flutter

I was trying out the firebase auth but when I added the dependencies I got some error.

Could you please check what the error?

This is the error that I got :

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   Android resource linking failed
>     Output:  D:\App\dipam\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

And this the dependencies that I added to the `pubspec.yaml` file :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  carousel_slider: ^1.0.1
  cloud_firestore: 0.8.2+3
  firebase_auth: 0.6.6
  google_sign_in: ^3.2.4

  shared_preferences:
  fluttertoast:
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted is a result of conflicting android.support and AndroidX versions. Make sure you're targeting API version 28.
In your app's `build.gradle` check if you have following values set

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28 // <-- Make sure you target API 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        targetSdkVersion 28 // <-- You need to update this value as well, or you might encounter runtime errors
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Also, make sure your not using old `android.support` libraries in your dependencies, but new AndroidX packaged. Check [this article](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility) for further references